# Installer Custom Action problem - can't write to register key

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation, custom-action

In the Custom Actions editor I've added the custom action to Install and Uninstall stages of the process. In the properties window I've marked the CustomActionData property as :

```
/TARGETDIR = "[TARGETDIR]"
```

I'm hoping that the above passes the installation directory info into the custom action.

The custom action seems to be firing, but I'm getting the following error message :

*"Error 1001. Can't write to register's key"* (or something like that, I'm translating it from my local language).

What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;
//using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace CustomActions
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class Installer1 : Installer
    {
        public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);

            const string key_path = "SOFTWARE\\VendorName\\MyAppName";
            const string key_value_name = "InstallationDirectory";

            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key_path);

            if (key == null)
            {
                key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(key_path);
            }

            string tgt_dir = Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"];

            key.SetValue(key_value_name, tgt_dir);

        }

        public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Uninstall(savedState);

            const string key_path = "SOFTWARE\\VendorName";
            const string key_name = "MyAppName";

            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key_path);

            if (key.OpenSubKey(key_name) != null)
            {
                key.DeleteSubKey(key_name);
            }
        }

        public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Rollback(savedState);
        }


        public Installer1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To install my registry keys I use "Registry View" where I change registry nodes.

Comment: And how do you set their values exactly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to change:
`RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key_path);`

To:
`RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key_path, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);`