# Setup and Deployment project adding a registry key

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry, setup-deployment

Within my VS2010 C# project I have created a Setup And Deployment project to install the windows app. This Application is being installed on internal pcs within my company. I need to change or add a certain registry key within the users PC registry file, but I am unclear on how to do it. I have read that you need to create a new registry file and export it but I dont want to replace theirs, all I want to do is create or update one registry key within a certian registry location.

I need to add "ForceLargerFonts" within the HKCU/software/Business Objects/10.5/Export location by either adding the location Pdf (if it doesnt exist) and then ultimately adding the registery DWORD key "ForceLargerFonts" and set its value to 1.

Can I have some help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Add Custom Action. For example see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782492/installer-custom-action-problem-cant-write-to-register-key)

Answer (score -1):

You should create a setup project it's allow you to write registry keys look at this may be it will helps you [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4dsy50b.aspx)

Comment: I would suggest this also.  Otherwise just create the key once.  Export it and then use a script to import it on each workstation on a reboot then delete the script.

Comment: the question needs to be read carefully next time, I stated I have a Setup and Deployment project

Comment: the link is broken @Serghei