# How add value on hkey_classes_root key where the application installed

Tags: c#, registry, windows-installer, url-protocol, visual-studio-setup

**Solved!!**

I am trying to create a Custom URL Protocol of my application that will launch my application when they visit or clicked link to myapp:start

My problem is how to know where the user installed my application. Can the msi installer put the location when registering HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT to registry?

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   myapp
      (Default) = "URL:myapp Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
           (Default) = "myapp.exe,1"
      shell
           open
               command
                   (Default) = "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder\MyApp.exe" "%1"
```

I wanted to change the path "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder\MyApp.exe" to where the user installed my app during installation process.

**Solution**

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   myapp
      (Default) = "URL:myapp Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
           (Default) = "myapp.exe,1"
      shell
           open
               command
                   (Default) = "[TARGETDIR]MyApp.exe "%1""
```

[TARGETDIR] will automatically change to where the user installed the file e.g. "C:\Program Files\MyAppFolder\"

For more information click this link -> 
[Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What are you using to create your MSI?

Comment: the normal setup project for visual studio 2010

Comment: Probably - but we'd need to know which specific technology you're using to author your installation package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Visual Studio Setup Project, you can use the `[TARGETDIR]` variable when creating your registry key.

This variable is automatically set to the target directory that your application is being installed into, simply append your `.exe` file to the end.

Comment: is it like this? (Default) = "[TARGETDIR]\MyApp.exe" "%1"

Comment: I don't have VS2010 around, but you can refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782492/installer-custom-action-problem-cant-write-to-register-key) which is doing the same thing. By the looks of things, you have a .reg file? It won't work from this.

Comment: **Wait**, [this site](http://codinglight.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/installing-startup-registry-key-in.html) is probably better.