# Installer Custom Action - Register COM dll - C#

Tags: c#, registry, installation, registrykey

I've created a COM visible project and have added an Setup Wizard to the project.
I've also added a Custom Actions class and have attempted to write to the registry.

Below is a sample entry for a wxs installer (which I have no experience in), how could i recreate this in C# during the install action of my custom actions class?

```
         <RegistryKey Root='HKCU' Key='Software\Autodesk\Structural\RSA\AddIns\{24D63E1C-E503-4EB4-9381-BF9F6A35E199}'>
      <RegistryValue Type='binary' Name='AddInsType' Value='0'/>
      <RegistryValue Type='binary' Name='Enable' Value='1'/>
      <RegistryValue Type='string' Name='File' Value='[INSTALLDIR]myaddin.dll'/>
      <RegistryValue Type='string' Name='Guid' Value='{24D63E1C-E503-4EB4-9381-BF9F6A35E199}'/>
      <RegistryValue Type='binary' Name='Guid Type' Value='2'/>
      <RegistryValue Type='binary' Name='KeepMenuGrade' Value='0'/>
      <RegistryValue Type='string' Name='KeyName' Value='{24D63E1C-E503-4EB4-9381-BF9F6A35E199}'/>
```

This is what I have so far in my custom actions class, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782492/installer-custom-action-problem-cant-write-to-register-key). Is it correct to add the key_value_name as the same GUID as my COM dll?

```
namespace RegisterRoboPython
{
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class RegisterRoboPython : Installer
{
    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);

        const string key_path = "Software\\Autodesk\\Structural\\RSA\\AddIns";
        const string key_value_name = "{5a0d8941-241c-481c-9811-2c76a91bf17c}";

        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key_path, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        if (key == null)
        {
            key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(key_path);
        }

        string tgt_dir = Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"];

        key.SetValue(key_value_name, tgt_dir);

    }


    public override void Commit(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);
    }

    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);

        const string key_path = "Software\\Autodesk\\Structural\\RSA\\AddIns";
        const string key_name = "{5a0d8941-241c-481c-9811-2c76a91bf17c}";

        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key_path);

        if (key.OpenSubKey(key_name) != null)
        {
            key.DeleteSubKey(key_name);
        }

    }

    public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Rollback(savedState);
    }

    public RegisterRoboPython()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
When running the installations .msi I receive the following error:

```
system.argumentexception FILE = DOES NOT EXIST 
IF THIS PARAMETER IS USED AS AN INSTALLER OPTION THE FORMAT MUST BE /KEY=[VALUE]
```

Which I am confused about as I have added `/TARGETDIR = "[TARGETDIR]"` to the install/commit CustomActionData properties.

So my question is, what is the correct way to register the COM dll using custom actions?

Am I on the right track?
Thanks for reading,
Tom

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Sorry @RobertHarvey I should have made myself more clear, please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

***Custom Action Avoidance***: Please try to avoid custom actions whenever you can. [Here is my propaganda against them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779). All you need to know is that they are error-prone. If there are built-in features that can do the same, use them instead.

---

> ***Registry View***: Following from [this description from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/906765/when-you-create-a-registry-key-and-a-value-in-a-visual-studio-setup-pr), please try to use this built-in feature:
>
> 1. Open your Visual Studio Project
> 2. On the **View** menu, point to **Editor**, and then click **Registry**.
> 3. Create keys and values as appropriate in the registry view

Please do consider sticking with [some other tool for deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840). At least read the description of limitations for Visual Studio Setup Projects below.

---

***Visual Studio Installer Projects Problems***: There are some issues with Visual Studio Installer Projects that you should know about. **Recommend you continue to use WiX**:

- [Why use Windows Installer XML (WiX) over VDPROJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635671/why-use-windows-installer-xml-wix-over-vdproj/2637666#2637666)
- [Visual Studio Publish Project Into One Simple Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893)

---

***Further Links***:

- [Getting Started With Setup Projects](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/)